# How can I cache images on the client side?

Tags: php, html

How can I cache images on the client side so the client doesn't request the same images again and again unless the server side images have changed?

Comment: every browser on the market does that; just make sure you are severing the correct headers for the images so the browser knows when it has or has not changed

Comment: What do you mean severing the correct headers?

Comment: Actually images are auto-cached on most web browsers.

Comment: unless you have changed your server set up, then you probably dont have to worry about it.

Comment: For example on Chrome you can view every thing Chrome has cached for you by going here `chrome://cache/`.

Comment: ^^ for firefox its `about:cache`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using apache and mod_expires:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

This tutorial may serve:
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/apache-module-mod-expires

Answer (score 3):

If you are dynamically creating the images in php, then you can use E-Tag's to help the browser cache the image.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-cache-etag.php